# cannot find file

Tags: java, file, csv, filenotfoundexception

```
private void readRandomContacts() throws IOException 
{

BufferedReader bufRdr;
contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

File randomContactsFile = new File("C:\randomContacts.csv");
try {
     bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(randomContactsFile));
     String line = null;
     String[] a = new String[2];

        while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    a = line.split(",");
                    Contacts c = new Contacts(a[0], a[1], a[1], a[1], a[2]);
                    contacts.add(c);
                }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("file not found", "check");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I cannot seem to make it find the file and randomContacts.csv does indeed exist in the C directory. Any help please?

Comment: yes a filenotfound exception! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
File randomContactsFile = new File("C:\\randomContacts.csv");
                                      ^^  these two are important
```

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) for some information about characters and escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

```
File randomContactsFile = new File("C:\randomContacts.csv");
```

should be

```
File randomContactsFile = new File("C:\\randomContacts.csv");
```

You need to escape `\`,otherwise, java would read `\r` as carriage return.

Comment: 10-04 14:54:47.009: WARN/System.err(333): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /C:/test/randomcontacts.txt (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this (frontslash):

```
new File("C:/randomContacts.csv")
```